# Inheriting from an abstract class in CPP

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been learning about CPP inheritance and I cam across this question:

```
   Class polygon contains data member width and height and public method set_value() to assign values to width and height.
 Class Rectangle and Triangle are inherited from polygon class. 
the classes contain public method calculate_area() to calculate the area of Rectangle and Triangle.
 Use base class pointer to access the derived class object and show the area calculated.
```

I wrote the following program for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Polygon{
    float height,width;
    public:
    void set_value(float height, float width){
        this->height=height;
        this->width=width;
    }
    virtual void calculate_area()=0;
};
class Rectangle:public Polygon{
    float height,width;
    public:
    void calculate_area(){
        cout << "Area of the rectangle is " << height*width <<endl;
    }
};
class Triangle:public Polygon{
    float height,width;
    public:
    void calculate_area(){
        cout << "Area of the triangle is " << 0.5*height * width << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Rectangle r1;
    r1.set_value(10,20);
    Triangle t1;
    t1.set_value(10,20);
    Polygon *p1;
    Polygon *p2;
    p1=&r1;
    p2=&t1;
    p1->calculate_area();
    p2->calculate_area();
    return 0;
}
```

However, on executing, it shows area of rectangle and triangle as zero. On further debugging, I found out that all dimensions (i.e. height and width of rectangle and triangle have value as zero). Can someone tell what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Tip: Use [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and avoid the `this->` mess in your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Triangle` and `Rectangle` inherit from `Polygon`, hence they also inherit `Polygon`s members `height` and `width`. Its those members that are used in `Polygon`s methods. Though they are `private`, hence cannot be accessed outside of `Polygon`.

`Triangle` and `Rectangle` have members `height` and `width` in addition to those inherited from `Polygon`. In `Triangle` and `Rectangle`s methods you are using those members. They are distinct from the members inherited from `Polygon`. Members of `Triangle` and `Rectangle` you do not initialize.

TL;DR: One possible fix is to grant derived classes access to the members by declaring them `protected` and remove the superflous definition of members in the derived classes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Polygon{
    protected:
    float height,width;
    public:
    void set_value(float height, float width){
        this->height=height;
        this->width=width;
    }
    virtual void calculate_area()=0;
};
class Rectangle:public Polygon{
    public:
    void calculate_area() override {
        cout << "Area of the rectangle is " << height*width <<endl;
    }
};
class Triangle:public Polygon{    
    public:
    void calculate_area() override {
        cout << "Area of the triangle is " << 0.5*height * width << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Rectangle r1;
    r1.set_value(10,20);
    Triangle t1;
    t1.set_value(10,20);
    Polygon *p1;
    Polygon *p2;
    p1=&r1;
    p2=&t1;
    p1->calculate_area();
    p2->calculate_area();
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/3KqvWfsaK):

```
Area of the rectangle is 200
Area of the triangle is 100
```

Note that I added `override` to the implementations of the virtual methods. When the overrides are ok, then it has not impact, but it will trigger a compiler error in case the method marked as `override` does actually not override (something that can happen easily by typos).

Comment: Width and height in class Polygon are private, how can they be inherited, I mean, isn't it that private data is never inherited?

Comment: @loveofprogramming no. A derived class inherits all the base class. `private` is just about visibility and access. In your code `Triangle` does inherit the members from `Polygon` it just cannot access them. If that wouldnt be the case it would not be possible to inherit from a base class. A class breaks when you remove its private parts

Comment: @loveofprogramming every `Triangle` has a complete intact `Polygon` subobject. That subobject would be of little use if it had its members removed